# Is there an href alternative for no-javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using javscript and classes to handle my click events like so:

```
<a class="forgotten" href="#">Forgot your password?</a>

$('.forgotten').click(function(){
    location.href = "forgotten.php"; 
    return false;
});
```

Is there a way to evaluate that function first and if javascript is disabled simply go to forgotten.php?

I know I could easily remove the class and add forgotten.php to href but I'm making heavy use of jquery address so it would break some of my site.

Comment: What benefit does your javascript have over just `href="forgotten.php"`?

Comment: I agree with tandu, you're not doing anything in the JS beyond using an <a> as it was intended, why involve JS at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, start by designing your markup so that it works even if the user has javascript disabled:

```
<a class="forgotten" href="/forgotten.php">Forgot your password?</a>
```

and then you could use unobtrusive javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('.forgotten').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "forgotten.php"; 
    });
});
```

obviously you probably want to do something more fancy in this javascript `.click()` handler other than simply redirecting to `forgotten.php` which is what an anchor with disabled javascript already does. You could do for example some progressive enhancement. Like an AJAX call with some animation or something.

Now if the user has javascript disabled he will simply be redirected to `forgotten.php`. And if he doesn't, well, put your imagination into action.

Comment: You should use `.preventDefault()` on the click event instead of `return false`.

Comment: excellent advice and it works great! The click event is to satisfy the jquery address module so nothing really fancy going on.

Comment: An additional advantage is that links can be opened via contexmenus.

Answer (score 0):

Using # as the href is bad practice, and isn't how to do things.

If you simply replace the # with forgotten.php, your code will do exactly what you want. The JS will be triggered first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with a scenario where javascript may be disable then I would take the opposite approach.  Start by formatting the HTML as you would if Javascript isn't there.  Then use javascript to format it as you would prefer after document load.